# Agile SCRUM: Horizontal versus vertical splitting

Tags: agile, scrum

We have a project which is going to last approximately 5 sprints.

The project involves a number of user stories, each story involving work by different developers: Web (AngularJS & ASP.NET MVC) and CRM (Dynamics). It is therefore 'Vertically Split'.

Each user story builds on the last: more fields being added to UI and more fields having to be picked up by CRM workflows. Testing each user story therefore requires re-visiting the user interface and back-end a number of times and testing the new fields just added.

Unusually, we have been asked to handle the sprint with 2 different types of task: the user story is put on one post it note, and the story has been further decomposed into the activities required by each developer (UI / CRM).  As a result we are actually ending up with two burn downs: this is something which I don't understand considering that we haven't provided estimates for the individual tasks.

I understand that splitting user stories vertically means that you are always going to deliver something useful, but I can't help but think this is not always going to be the most efficient way of delivering the project, especially when you consider you're revisiting the same parts of the application again and again.

Is there any scenario where a horizontal splitting is acceptable in scrum agile, as in our case it would allow a CRM developer to implement their work in a separate user story? After all, if it's early on in the sprint, the risks of not implementing a feature in the developers respective layer is quite small. Furthermore, there wouldn't be a need to decompose the user story into further 'tasks'.

By decomposing tasks into horizontal (architectural) tasks in this case, we can make the UI changes in a few days and then get the CRM developer to pick up the data that we send across in a separate story. I think this would also make it far easier to test, because you are testing each complete 'feature' in it's respective environment rather than building it up across several user stories....

Obviously if you are a full stack developer it's a lot easier to achieve vertical splitting,. But it's not the case with this project....

What is the suggested approach where you have an application which is consistently increasing the number of fields / UI? Is horizontal splitting of tasks ever permitted in agile or is it always a no-no?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that even if you split the tasks horizontally you will achieve what you'd like. Let's take an extreme example where UI developer completes 100% of his tasks while CRM developer completes none of his.

Will there be any feature released (or any user story fulfilled)? I guess not.

Therefore, I would suggest to address the UI and CRM developers as one unit (with common burndown) and split the tasks internally between them.
Preferably, they will work in similar tempo so they can provide each other with tasks to complete. 
Also, this cooperation can be a good thing as both UI and CRM developers will feel more commitment to the project since they have a common goal and measured as a common unit.

Hope it sounds reasonble and helps you to make a decision.

Answer (score 0):

This is where the concept of swarming comes in.  Assuming your scrum team consists of members with technical competencies that cover all aspects of the user story (e.g. UI, CRM, DB, etc), then your scrum team can swarm the first user story working together to complete all aspects at the same time.  Assuming you have a tester embedded on your team, they can be writing test cases for it at the same time as well.  In a day or two that story is done and you have something fully functional and demonstrable to your product owner/stakeholder.  Then the team swarms the next user story.  It takes time for a team to get into a rhythm to be able to do this effectively, about 6-12 months in my experience for a team without prior experience working this way to do so.

Also by doing the entire vertical path up front you learn what is needed early and can make changes quickly before there is a lot of code to refactor.  If you do an entire layer first and then the next layer, besides not being able to test that first layer yet, you end up finding things when implementing the next layer that will cause you to have to go back and redo the first layer.  This results in extra work or creates non-maintainable code as things are hacked in to meet deadlines.

Comment: I have read about this and I understand why this 'should' work. However it's not working in our current situation. I'm guess we're failing because of the way that the user stories have been split up and because the CRM resource is far smaller than the web resource.
There are about 3 or 4 user stories which involve incrementally adding fields to the UI in subsequent stories which in turn involves changing the API and in turn involves incrementally adding more fields to CRM workflows. 
All the user stories are in 'doing' because there are 3 developers on the front end and only 1 CRM developer.

Comment: Because we are under-resourced in the CRM area, the CRM developer is being swamped with all the changes at once. So in a way it would be far more efficient to tackle all the CRM stuff at once as a seperate user story. This in turn would result in user stories moving across the board and tackled more efficiently. But we're not allowed to do that because it's not agile!

If we do not have the CRM resource, is this basically not allowing us to work agile properly or is there something that we could do to improve the user stories?

Comment: Another thing I mentioned was having developer tasks seperated from user stories which I think is confusing. Am I right in thinking that the technical implementation should have been added in the acceptance criteria rather than handled as seperate actions? 

Given our situation and lack of resources, is 'agile' the right methodolgy to use?!

Comment: Can one of the front end developers begin cross-training to learn how to aid the CRM developer?  Even if it is more along the line of pair-programming with the current CRM developer taking the lead?  It sounds like a staffing issue that needs to be worked around.  Though there can be some reluctance by some to go outside their comfort zone.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and will probably follow this approach.  Despite this I still can't help but think the 'Agile way' is not necessarily the most efficient way... There are different scenarios like this that can put a spanner in the works....